# WIX - Error TRCH0103

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to create a multi-language MSI. Therefore I use torch to create transform files.
With some languges it works and with others I got the following error. 
Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks Sabine

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin>torch.exe -t language "Release\en-US\Testprog.msi" "Release\de-DE\Testprog.msi" -out "transforms\de-DE.mst"
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Transform Builder version 3.5.2519.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin>torch.exe -t language "Release\en-US\Testprog.msi" "Release\pt_pt\Testprog.msi" -out "transforms\pt-pt.mst"
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Transform Builder version 3.5.2519.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

torch.exe : error TRCH0103 : The system cannot find the file 'C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\Release\pt_pt\Testprog.msi' with type 'Database'.
```

The file Testprog.msi exits int the "pt_pt" folder and works standalone.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything else I would test with full paths to all files in the command line just to verify that the command actually fails with a torch.exe error and not some sort of windows path issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the second command runs (for pt_pt) the current directory is /bin folder of WiX install location. You can see it from the path the error message displays. And I bet there's no "Release\pt_pt\Testprog.msi" in WiX /bin folder. If you find out why the current directory gets switched, you'll resolve the problem.